# ant : delete directories whose name is entirely numeric

Tags: regex, ant

I'm trying to write an ant target that deletes folders *in the current directory only*, whose name consists entirely of digits.

My directory structure is:

```
|
+-02/
+-11/
+-reports/
```

I only want it to delete folders 02 and 11.

What I have tried is a simple regex in `fileset` `includes`:

```
<delete verbose='true' includeemptydirs="true" failonerror="no">
    <fileset dir="." includes="[0-9]+" />
</delete>
```

This doesn't match anything..
Hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When on Windows use:

```
<delete verbose="true" includeemptydirs="true">
 <fileset dir="C:/your/root/dir" defaultexcludes="false" >
  <filename regex="\d+\\"/>
 </fileset>
</delete>
```

on Unix use

```
<filename regex="\d+/"/>
```

Note the use of `path.separator` after `\d+`
Otherwise `/rootdir/withoutdigits/subdir/123.txt` would also be deleted !